# Swift How can i get variable from another method in same class

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I'm a beginner of swift.
I wrote code and one question.
I want to get variable `b` from func `A` but I don't know how.
How to get it.

```
/*This is extension from FirstViewController*/
extension FirstViewController{

    private func A() {
        let a:CGFloat  = view.frame.size.width
        let b:CGFloat  = view.frame.size.height
    }

    private func B() {
        self.Something.frame.size = CGSize(width: /*I want to get a in here*/, height: /*I want to get b in here*/)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that the actual solution to your problem depends highly on what you *actually* want to do (your ultimate goal).

---

You can't access `a` or `b` in `B` because `a` and `b` are in a different scope from `B`. You can't access local variables declared in a function from another function.

To access them, you need to move `a` and `b` to a scope that is accessible by `B`. In this case, this can be the scope of the extension:

```
extension FirstViewController{
    var a: CGFloat { return view.frame.size.width }
    var b: CGFloat { return view.frame.size.height }
    private func A() {

    }

    private func B() {
        self.Something.frame.size = CGSize(width: a, height: b)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I solved my problem!! Your code is very simple and minimal!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a **`Tuple`** of type **`(CGFloat, CGFloat)`** to achieve that, i.e.

```
private func A() -> (a: CGFloat, b: CGFloat)
{
    let a:CGFloat  = view.frame.size.width
    let b:CGFloat  = view.frame.size.height
    return (a, b)
}

private func B()
{
    self.Something.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.A().a, height: self.A().b)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I solved my problem!! 
Your way is also wonderful

Comment: Sure..Happy coding,,:)